# Set label for series Radar chart Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to add a label to my radar chart legend in google scripts (Sheets). The series are working just fine, and the legend is produced. However, no title is added to the series, meaning I do have the small color indication, but no text with it.

I tried looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart), but that does not seem to work for radar charts.

Basically the code is as follows:

```
  var chartnew = resultSheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.RADAR)
    .setPosition(30, 3, 0, 0)  
    .addRange(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(CalcSheetName).getRange("A16:A25"))
    .addRange(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(CalcSheetName).getRange("B16:B25"))
    .addRange(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(CalcSheetName).getRange("C16:C25"))
    .setOption("title", "title")
    .setOption('legend', {position: 'left'})
    .setOption('series', {0:{labelInLegend: 'A'}, 1:{labelInLegend:'B'}})
    .setOption('width', 450)
    .setOption('height',370)
    .build();
    resultSheet.insertChart(chartnew);
```

One thing to notice is the addition of three datasources, but the graph only shows two, as desired.

How can I add these label/serie titles in a radar graph (Google scripts)

Answer (score -1):

#### Quick answer :

> in order to add labels to your charts you have to generate lables and add them manually to your charts

The way I did it:

#### 1. My data:

[image]

#### 2. Script which will create radar chart:

```
function createRadarChart() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.RADAR)
      .addRange(ss.getRange('C2:D8'))
      .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
      .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
      .setNumHeaders(1)
      .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
      .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
      .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
      .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
      .setOption('title', 'Age')
      .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
      .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
      .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
      .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
      .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
      .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
      .setOption('hAxis.title', 'Name')
      .setOption('vAxes.0.title', 'Age')
      .setPosition(10, 5, 77, 15)
      .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

#### 3. Create text

Once done go to Insert > Drawing and create some text
[image]
Save and close

#### 4. Drag it to your chart

[image]

### References:

- [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts)

Comment: I cannot have any interference so this won't work unfortunally.

Comment: In this case I would suggest you find a way to generate your text as an image and than attach it with Apps Script.